# Packets drops at physical function for SR-IOV configured on KVM host- Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization

Configured KVM host and intel nic XXV710 in SR-IOV mode. Configured virtual function in a guest vm but not able to reach guest ip from host.

```
Host physical interface : ethtool -i eth1
driver: i40e
version: 2.15.9
firmware-version: 6.02 0x80003888 255.65535.255
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: 0000:81:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: yes

ls -l /sys/class/net/eth1/device/virtfn*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Nov  3 23:50 /sys/class/net/eth1/device/virtfn0 -> ../0000:81:02.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Nov  3 23:50 /sys/class/net/eth1/device/virtfn1 -> ../0000:81:02.1

ifconfig eth1
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:12:52:FC  
inet addr:10.5.136.207  Bcast:10.5.255.255  Mask:255.255.128.0
inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:fe12:52fc/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
RX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
RX bytes:322 (322.0 b)  TX bytes:362 (362.0 b)

[root@oak-cs849-vcs15 ~]# ping 10.5.136.207
PING 10.5.136.207 (10.5.136.207) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.5.136.207: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.046 ms
64 bytes from 10.5.136.207: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.017 ms

root@oak-cs849:~# ping 10.5.136.207 -I eth1
ping: Warning: source address might be selected on device other than: eth1
PING 10.5.136.207 (10.5.136.207) from 10.5.69.61 eth1: 56(84) bytes of data.
```

Comment: cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal

Comment: I am also seeing error oui Unknown in ping reply

Comment: I feel host does not recognise the virtual function and thus pf is dropping the packets

Comment: Any help related to why vf is not detected by pf?